# Integral of $\int \frac {1}{1+x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to tackle with this problem

$$\int \frac {1}{1+x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

I have put $x$ = $\sin y$. But couldn't reach at the final result.

Please help....

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Put $x = 1/y$...
The given integral will transform into

$\frac{-1}{y^2 + \sqrt{y^2-1}} dy$

Rationalize and see what you get...

Answer (score 1):

Following the substitution $x=\sin y$
\begin{align}
&\int \frac {1}{1+x \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx\\
=& \int \frac{\cos y}{1+\sin y\cos y}
= \frac12\int \frac{\cos y+\sin y}{1+\sin y\cos y}
 +\frac{\cos y - \sin y}{1+\sin y\cos y}\ dy\\
=& \ \int \frac{d(\sin y-\cos y)}{3-(\sin y-\cos y)^2}
 +\int \frac{d(\sin y +\cos y)}{1+(\sin y+\cos y)^2}\\
=& \ \frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sin y-\cos y}{\sqrt3}
+\tan^{-1}(\sin y+\cos y)\\
=& \ \frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt3}
+\tan^{-1}\left(x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** After making the suggested substitution $x = \sin y$, one can transform the resulting integral, which is rational in $\sin y$ and $\cos y$, into a rational function using the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) $y = 2 \arctan t$. Alternately, one can eliminate the middle step and carry out both substitutions at once, substituting
$$x = \sin (2 \arctan t) = \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}, \quad dx = -\frac{2 (t^2 - 1)}{(t^2 + 1)^2};$$
This substitution looks to produce
$$- 2 \int \frac{t^2 - 1}{t^4 + 2 t^3 + 2 t^2 - 2 t + 1}.$$
The denominator factors as a product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials (but not over $\mathbb{Q}$, some coefficients contain rational multiples of $\sqrt{3}$), and so once (1) one finds these one can (2) proceed with the method of partial fractions, (3) integrate the resulting terms of the form $$\frac{A t + B}{t^2 + C t + D}$$ in the usual way, and (4) back-substitute for the original variable $x$. In particular, the antiderivative is elementary, but consulting a CAS shows that it is somewhat messy.